# Temporary column, count and Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server and trying to learn the ropes in here. I am currently using SQL Server Management Studio v17.9

I have two tables `Product` and `Receipt` with one column in common (`ProductID`).

I need to create a query that can show how many times a product has been sold and create a temporary column with flavor text on it.

Something like this:

```
ID          Name                 Times Sold    Movement
----------- -------------------- ------------- -------------
1           Smart TV LED 42p     1             Little Movement
27          Teatro en Casa       2             Few Movement
37          smartphone AG        0             No Movement
47          refrigerador         4             Normal Movement
```

I came up with this

```
SELECT
    p.Idprod 'ID',
    p.name 'Product Name',
    COUNT(df.idprod) 'Times Sold',
    Movement = (CASE
                   WHEN 'Times Sold' = 0 THEN 'No Movement'
                   WHEN 'Times Sold' = 1 THEN 'Little Movement'
                   WHEN 'Times Sold' = 2 THEN 'Few Movement'
                   WHEN 'Times Sold' = 3 THEN 'Few Movement'
                   ELSE 'Normal Movement' 
                END)
FROM
    product p 
FULL JOIN 
    DetailsReciepts df ON p.IdProd = df.idProd
GROUP BY
    p.IdProd, p.name
```

This spits out the error message:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Times Sold' to data type int

I tried `Convert()`, setting temporary statements like `@SoldTimes` and `@Movement`, finally tried `IF` with no luck. Tried to search the web, I'm stuck.

Comment: One expression in the select can't reference another expression in the same select. Either use nested queries or just put `COUNT(df.idprod)` in the `CASE` expression *(instead of `'Times Sold'`, which is being seen as a literal STRING rather than a column name.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query you seem to want:

```
select p.Idprod as id, p.name as Product_Name,
       count(df.idProd) as num_sold,
       (case when count(df.idProd) = 0 then 'No Movement'
             when count(df.idProd) = 1 then 'Little Movement'
             when count(df.idProd) <= 3 then 'Few Movement'
             else 'Normal Movement'
        end) as movement
from product p left join 
     DetailsReciepts df 
     on p.IdProd = df.idProd
group by p.IdProd, p.name;
```

Notes:

- `full join` is almost never appropriate in a well-designed database.  You want all the products, so it should be the first table in the `from`.  Then use `left join`.
- Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for date and time constants.  When you confuse strings and column names, you get problems, as your version of the query shows.
- If you need to escape the column aliases, use double quotes or square braces.
- I recommend not mixing `as` and `=` for column assignments.  The `<alias> =` is a SQL Server extension; I recommend at least starting with `as` for all assignments.

Comment: Such dumb error to make, Very illustrative, Thank you very much for the notes, I'll take them to heart!

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference the calculated column 'Times Sold' within your query.  You would need to create another table that has Times Sold calculated, likely either as a CTE, temp table, or derived table.

Without knowing much about your tables, you could try with a CTE:

```
;with timesSold as (
select 
    p.Idprod 'ID',
    p.name 'Product Name',
    COUNT(df.idprod) 'Times Sold'
from 
    product p FULL JOIN DetailsReciepts df 
    on p.IdProd = df.idProd
group by
    p.IdProd, 
    p.name
)
select ts.*
   , 'Movement' = 
        (case
            when Times Sold=0 then 'No Movement'
            when Times Sold=1 then 'Little Movement'
            when Times Sold=2 then 'Few Movement'
            when Times Sold=3 then 'Few Movement'
            else 'Normal Movement' end)
from 
    timesSold ts
```

For more specific info on the error you're getting, 'Times Sold' is just a string literal.  It doesn't reference the calculated column Times Sold that you want it to.  So when you ask the case statement to compare if 'Time Sold' is equal to a number, it tries to converte 'Times Sold' to an int to do so, and fails.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand what this code is doing:

```
when 'Times Sold'=3 then 'Few Movement'
```

You are not comparing the value of `COUNT(df.idprod)` with a number. You are comparing the literal string `'Times Sold'` with a number.

If you dispense with the alias inside the `case` block, this will work.

```
select 
    p.Idprod 'ID',
    p.name 'Product Name',
    COUNT(df.idprod) 'Times Sold',
    (case
            when COUNT(df.idprod)=0 then 'No Movement'
            when COUNT(df.idprod)=1 then 'Little Movement'
            when COUNT(df.idprod)=2 then 'Few Movement'
            when COUNT(df.idprod)=3 then 'Few Movement'
            else 'Normal Movement' 
       end ) Movement
from 
    product p FULL JOIN DetailsReciepts df 
    on p.IdProd = df.idProd
group by
    p.IdProd, 
    p.name
```

You can assign an alias to a query result value, but you cannot use that alias within the same query. 
You can, however, use the alias within an outer query.

This will also work, and may be preferable:

```
select 
    subquery.ID,
    subquery.[Product Name],
    subquery.[Times Sold],
    (case
            when subquery.[Times Sold]=0 then 'No Movement'
            when subquery.[Times Sold]=1 then 'Little Movement'
            when subquery.[Times Sold]=2 then 'Few Movement'
            when subquery.[Times Sold]=3 then 'Few Movement'
            else 'Normal Movement' 
       end ) Movement
from (
     select
        p.Idprod 'ID',
        p.name 'Product Name',
        COUNT(df.idprod) 'Times Sold'
     from
       product p FULL JOIN DetailsReciepts df
        on p.IdProd = df.idProd
     group by 
        p.IdProd, p.Name
) subquery
```